# Bootstrap collapse select first and last child with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

any advice how to select first and last child of Bootstrap collapse module? I need to select ".accordion-heading" first and last..

```
  <div id="accordion2" class="accordion">
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"><br />
    Toggle Accordion 1<br />
    </a></div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"><br />
    Toggle Accordion 2<br />
    </a></div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" href="#collapseThree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"><br />
    Toggle Accordion 3<br />
    </a></div>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PzB8D/1/

You must go to `accordion-group` first, then refer to `accordion-heading` There's gonna be the only one element with class `accordion-heading`:)

```
.accordion-group:first-child .accordion-heading a{color: #f00;}
.accordion-group:last-child .accordion-heading a{color: #0f0;}
```